# PHP ZipArchive stopped working

Tags: php, csv, zip

I have a script which takes a zipped CSV file, unzips it, and removes duplicate entries. It was mostly working, until I moved the unzip code into a function. Now it fails to unzip the .zip file, but doesn't show an error.

Checked file/folder permissions, everything is 777 on dev machine.

```
<?php
//
//huge memory limit for large files
$old = ini_set('memory_limit', '8192M');
//
//create a string like the filename
$base_filename = 'csv-zip-file'.date('m').'_'.date('d').'_'.date('Y');
//
//if the file exists ...
//unzip it
//read it to an array
//remove duplicates
//save it as a new csv
if (file_exists($base_filename.'.zip')) {
    $zip_filename = $base_filename.'.zip';
    echo "The file <strong>$zip_filename</strong> exists<br>";
    unzip($zip_filename);
    $csv = csv_to_array();
    $csv = unique_multidim_array($csv,"Project Id");
    var_dump($csv);
} else {
    echo "The file <strong>$base_filename.zip</strong> does not exist";
}


function unzip($file_to_unzip) {
    $zip=new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($file_to_unzip)==TRUE) {
        $address=__DIR__;
        $zip->extractTo($address);
        $res=$zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}

function csv_to_array () {
//    global $filename;
    global $base_filename;
    $rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($base_filename.'.csv'));
    //using array_pop to remove the copyright on final row
    array_pop($rows);
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $csv = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    return $csv;
}
```

Comment: side note: That's a weird memory allotment.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem you have here.

1. Output `$file_to_unzip` right inside the function.
2. Does $zip->* have an `last_error` or `last_response` method? See
   what the ZipArchive class IS returning.
3. Do you have access to the php error logs? Let's look there for any output.

Comment: For item 1, assume you mean "echo $file_to_unzip;" that looks right.

I checked methods for zip, there's a "getStatusString" method which when I look in the error logs says:

PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::getStatusString(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Comment: Just after init'ing the ZipArchive object go step by step, line by line, through the process as you want it to work. Find the location it stops working as intended. This is sounding like a scope issue ATM.